# How can I group by latest dates and IDs, yet take into account all data from previous dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So my example table is like this -
I have a mysql version 5.7 database which I  can connect to. Read-only rights. 
My table goes like this:

```
human_id | dog_id | dog_bought_at | amount_paid_for_dog | purchase_place | buyer_has_criminal_past
       1 |      1 | 27-12-2019    |                 100 | Tokyo          |                       0
       1 |      2 | 03-01-2020    |                 200 | Moscow         |                       0
       2 |      3 | 03-01-2020    |                 200 | Los Angeles    |                       0
       3 |      4 | 03-01-2020    |                  50 | Washington     |                       0
       3 |      3 | 05-01-2020    |                  30 | Dallas         |                       0
       4 |      2 | 06-01-2020    |                 150 | Texas          |                       1
```

What I need to show is this:

```
dog_id | last_owner_id | total_amount_paid_for_dog | last_purchase_date | last_purchase_place
     1 |             1 |                       100 |         27-12-2019 | Tokyo
     2 |             4 |                       350 |         06-01-2020 | Moscow
     3 |             3 |                       230 |         05-01-2020 | Dallas
     4 |             3 |                        50 |         03-01-2020 | Washington
```

Last_purchase_place is shown only for those humans, which do not have criminal past.
what I have tried:

```
SELECT
    e.dog_id
    ,MAX(e.human_id) last_owner_id
    ,SUM(e.amount_paid_for_dog) total_amount_paid_for_dog
    ,MAX(e.dog_bought_at) last_purchase_date        
    ,e_filter.purchase_place last_purchase_place
FROM example e
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        dog_id
        ,dog_bought_at
        ,purchase_place
        ,human_id
    FROM example
    WHERE buyer_has_criminal_past != 1
) e_filter ON e.dog_id = e_filter.dog_id AND e.dog_bought_at = e_filter.dog_bought_at
```

But I am stuck on the logic, that allows to sum up ALL amounts, yet filter out unneeded values.
This is my first question here, so if this is a duplicate or not well written, please say it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: 2 | 1 |  350 so you will show sum of 350 for this example even do human id 4 has a criminal past ?

Comment: Thank You for noting - that's not correct, humans and dates are shown as the last ones, will edit

Comment: Create fiddle (or post CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO at least) instead of table-form example data.

Comment: @raivol, your edit is not correct! Human with ID = 4 has a criminal past!

Comment: No access to that.. Read-only rights, I am using dbeaver to connect to the db.

Comment: @VBoka, I probably did not define my question then: buyers are in fact shown, but the place is the last place for non-criminal past having buyers

Comment: The real query is way more difficult and includes more columns to filter by, this is just the bare-bones basic example which I can think of. This is the case where I have no access to CREATE TABLE and communication with client and IT is not giving any results for me. Sorry, guys, this is what I have..

Comment: @VBoka, yep. Sum ALL amounts, show last owners, purchase dates (which makes actually one of these example fields redundant), but place is shown only for the last purchase for non-criminal past having buyers. I know it sounds totally absurd, but I am not able to post my real example due to privacy reasons, there are different fields. this is the best I could think of at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT e1.dog_id, 
       e1.human_id last_owner_id, 
       sq1.total_amount_paid_for_dog, 
       e1.dog_bought_at last_purchase_date, 
       e2.purchase_place last_purchase_place
FROM example e1
JOIN ( SELECT dog_id, 
              MAX(dog_bought_at) dog_bought_at, 
              SUM(amount_paid_for_dog) total_amount_paid_for_dog
       FROM example
       GROUP BY dog_id ) sq1 ON e1.dog_id = sq1.dog_id
                            AND e1.dog_bought_at = sq1.dog_bought_at
LEFT JOIN example e2 ON e1.dog_id = e2.dog_id
JOIN ( SELECT dog_id, 
              MAX(dog_bought_at) dog_bought_at
       FROM example
       WHERE buyer_has_criminal_past = 0
       GROUP BY dog_id ) sq2 ON e2.dog_id = sq2.dog_id
                            AND e2.dog_bought_at = sq2.dog_bought_at
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6f23b40af99589d998ee5258b7eb7cc1)